# subscriber does not get posted message from eventBus

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I want to use eventbus into my app. for that I add eventbus lib to my gradle.then I have created a class like this:

```
public class UserEvent {

private User eUser; // esup user model
private String domain;
private String securitySrv;
private Cookie cookie;
private int totalUsersSecurity;
private ExecutorService executorService;
// constructor and getter
```

then into main fragment I have added this lines and finally I have posted my message:

```
UserEvent userEvent = new UserEvent(eUser, domain, securitySrv, cookie,
totalUsersSecurity, executorService);
EventBus.getDefault().post(userEvent);
```

into main fragment I have ViewPager that this pager have loaded another fragment called **AllUsersFragment**.

In AllUsersFragment first I have registered eventbus:

```
EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    bus.register(this);
    return rootView;
}
```

and then i wrote this method:

```
    @Subscribe
public void onEvent(UserEvent event) {
    securitySrv = event.getSecuritySrv();
    cookie = event.getCookie();
    totalUsersSecurity = event.getTotalUsersSecurity();
    executorService = event.getExecutorService();

}
```

into my resume method I want to pass `UserEvent` from eventbus to another class by its constructor:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    paginator = new Paginator(getContext(),totalUsersSecurity,executorService);

}
```

but totalUsersSecurity and executorService are null? while these variables was fill at main fragment.in debug mod at android studio this `public void onEvent(UserEvent event)` is not never called.
thank you for helping?

I am using android studio 3 with `gradle:3.0.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fix this problem. according [eventBus wiki](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/)

I just use **Sticky Events** .now I received my post

Answer (score 0):

have you registered for the event on `OnStart()`

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

Comment: I have registered at onCreateView()