# Use EventBus at simple class

Tags: android, event-bus

I have a problem into subscriber at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495649/subscriber-does-not-get-posted-message-from-eventbus/47496280#47496280) and I solve that. my subscriber was a fragment. ***But now my subscriber is a simple class.Is it possible ?***

Because I got this error:

```
org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.safa.musers.MainActivity and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
```

I am using in this way:

```
public class Paginator {

EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
private Context ctx;
private String securitySrv;
private int totalItems;
private ExecutorService executorService;
private Cookie cookie;

public Paginator(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    bus.register(ctx);
}
```

And finally for receive post:

```
    @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(UserEvent event) {
    securitySrv = event.getSecuritySrv();
    cookie = event.getCookie();
    totalItems = event.getTotalUsersSecurity();
    executorService = event.getExecutorService();
}
```

But I got above Error.thank you for helping

My MainActivity is not subscribe an event or post an event.

Comment: I think got your problem. Please check using this instead of context. Like

public Paginator(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    bus.register(this);
}

Comment: Ok .I am trying

Comment: You register your eventbus using this keyword not context. I was checking if  i use context got your similar problem.

Comment: thank you dude.its work.

Comment: But I have to use postSticky.

Comment: postSticky means?

Comment: @ShohelRana yes.

Comment: postSticky not working ?

Comment: postSticky working but post not working.@ShohelRana

Comment: I have no idea. its working for me :(